# Convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n \tan{(n)}}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, proof-explanation

Convergence/divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{(-1)}^n \tan{(n)}}{n^2}$$
I thought diverge because some value $n \approx \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k \implies \tan{n}=\pm \infty$ but key says that this never holds because $\pi$ is irrational.  He said $\tan{n}$ is bounded and clearly series without $\tan{n}$ converges.  Someone can explain this further to me please?

Comment: Are we sure that $\tan n$ is bounded on $\mathbb{N}$? Sure, $\pi$ is irrational, but depending on how close a point from $\mathbb{N}$ can approximate an odd multiple of $\pi/2$, an arbitrary number of terms could get arbitrarily large.

Comment: "tangent is bounded"; that is nonsense. Using the fact that $\cos(n)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$, there is a subsequence $\theta_n$ such that $\cos(\theta_n)$ is decreasing and approaches $0$; one could have $\cos(\theta_n)<1/n$, for instance. It follows that $\tan(\theta_n)$ is unbounded.

Comment: It is hard to believe that the key can claim that $\tan n$ is bounded.

Comment: @Integrand Sorry I wrote it bad.  "It’s clear that $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$ cannot be an integer if k is an integer. This implies that the sequence $a_n=\tan{n}$ is bounded. Let the maximum value of the sequence occur at $n=r$ (note $\tan{(r)}$ would be finite).  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\tan{(n)}}{n^2} < \frac{\pi^2 \tan{(r)}}{6}$$

Comment: @user: if we assume that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $2$ then $\frac{\tan n}{n}$ does not have a limit but *it is* bounded.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose In this case it is hard to explain why does the key discuss irrationality of $\pi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ be a convergent of the continued fraction of $\pi$ such that $q_n$ is odd and $p_n$ is even. We have
$$ \left|\frac{\pi}{2} q_n - \frac{p_n}{2} \right| \leq \frac{1}{2q_n} $$
and since both $\sin$ and $\cos$ are Lipschitz-continuous we have
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{p_n}{2}\right)\right|\geq 1-\frac{1}{2q_n}\approx 1-\frac{\pi}{4(p_n/2)}, $$
$$\left|\cos\left(\frac{p_n}{2}\right)\right|\leq \frac{1}{2q_n}\approx \frac{\pi}{4(p_n/2)} $$
so there is a sequence of natural numbers $n$ such that $|\tan(n)|$ is at least as large as $\left(\frac{2}{\pi}-\varepsilon\right)n$.
If we assume that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $>3$ we have that $\frac{\tan n}{n^2}$ is not even bounded.
On the other hand the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is still unknown (it is conjectured to be $2$, but nowadays we only know that it is $\leq 7.11$), so to discuss the convergence of such series, like the [Flint Hills series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FlintHillsSeries.html), is pretty pointless.
Your series is probably convergent since $(-1)^n$ has bounded partial sums and $\frac{\tan(n)}{n^2}$ is probably convergent to zero without wild oscillations, but we currently lack the technology for proving such a claim.

Comment: Thanks for post.  This is for a grade 11-12 calculus competition so this problem seems strange difficulty.

Comment: The author of the question was almost certainly unaware of its difficulty.